# Custom CSS - remove margin bottom in my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar, margins

Hey I have what should be a simple question. I need to remove a "margin-bottom:10px" in my html code for my TOP LEFT NAVIGATION BAR (facebook, instagram, twitter) using custom css.  It is the container for the images for my social media icons.

Here is the code:

```
<a class="synved-social-button synved-social-button-follow synved-social-size-18 synved-social-resolution-single synved-social-provider-facebook nolightbox" data-provider="facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" 
href="https://www.facebook.com/orangecountyhydroponicsupplies" style="font-size: 0px; width:18px;height:18px;margin:0;margin-bottom:10px;">
<img alt="facebook" class="synved-share-image synved-social-image synved-social-image-follow" width="18" height="18" style="display: inline; width:18px;height:18px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; box-shadow: none;" 
src="https://www.greenenvysupply.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-feather/synved-social/image/social/regular/48x48/facebook.png"></a>
```

Again I need to use Custom CSS to remove the bottom-margin
Please and thanks!
[Greenenvysupply.com](http://greenenvysupply.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#menu-top-left li.menu-item > a {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: no worries. please mark as correct by clicking the tick under the up and down arrows next to the question

Answer (score 0):

You're using inline-style. You can only override that with `!important`, but you should try to avoid inline-style and only use `!important` if you have a specific case.

```
li.menu-item > a {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

If you want to keep it nice give all the anchors the following class. You'll keep it specific for only the elements that really need no margin

```
.no-margin {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change `top-bar` `padding-bottom` `0px`

```
.top-bar{
padding: 10px 0 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you also need to set same font-size for icon links.

```
li.menu-item > a {
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  padding: 0 11px !important;
}
```

Comment: Not the case actually.  This change didn't do anything relevant, just messed up the font.  I have solved the issue thanks.